# A simple code that worked fine under GC but started crashing in ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following simple "check whether my app is set to launch at login" code. It worked fine under garbage collection. However, since I started using ARC (and inserted the "`__bridge`" as necessary), the code started randomly and unpredictably crashing. According to the stack trace, the code crashes during some `CFRelease`. Any ideas what might be causing this to happen under ARC?

```
- (BOOL)loginItemExists
{
  NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
  LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL,
                                     kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems, NULL);
  BOOL found = NO;  
  UInt32 seedValue;
  CFURLRef thePath;
  CFArrayRef loginItemsArray = LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItems,
                                                              &seedValue);
  for (id item in (__bridge NSArray *)loginItemsArray)
  {    
    LSSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)item;
    if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve(itemRef, 0, &thePath, NULL) == noErr)
    {
      if ([[(__bridge NSURL *)thePath path] hasPrefix:appPath])
        found = YES;
    }

    //docs for LSSharedFileListItemResolve say we should release the CFURLRef
    if (thePath != NULL)
      CFRelease(thePath);

    if (found)
      break;
  }

  CFRelease(loginItemsArray);
  CFRelease(loginItems);
  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get a double-free here the second time through the loop if the item doesn't resolve. Set thePath to nil at the beginning and also after releasing it and that will fix the crash.

Comment: Would you say my `if (thePath != NULL)` check is unnecessary? I mean, is `CFRelease(NULL)` allowed? If it is, my check is probably unnecessary.

Comment: The argument to CFRelease must not be NULL, the test is required.

Answer (score -1):

you could disable ARC by adding a Compiler Flag -fno-objc-arc to the specific file
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, in this case I would prefer not disabling ARC, and instead try to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Besides, nothing is being managed by ARC anyway, since I'm doing regular `__bridge`. That seems to imply that the same problem would occur under manual memory management. The problem seems to be that it's the GC -> non-GC transition that introduced the problem. Not ARC per se.