# ARC lead to crash CoreFoundation object

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I have a part of code which sometimes crashes on OSX system on client side but I can't reproduce the crash. I have only few assumptions but I don't want to make blind fix. I just want to be convinced with the fix:

```
+ (NSArray *)loginItems:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {

    LSSharedFileListRef list = [self loginItemsFileListRef];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *items = [self loginItemsForFileListRef:list];
    CFRelease(list);
    for (id item in items) {
        LSSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)item;
        [result addObject:[self loginItemFromItemRef:itemRef]];
    }
    return result;
}

+ (NSDictionary *)loginItemFromItemRef:(LSSharedFileListItemRef)itemRef {
    NSMutableDictionary *itemDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    // Name
    CFStringRef nameRef = LSSharedFileListItemCopyDisplayName(itemRef);
    if (nameRef) {
        NSString *name = (__bridge NSString *)nameRef;
        itemDict[RESLoginItemsNameKey] = name.stringByDeletingPathExtension;
        CFRelease(nameRef);
    }
    // Path
    CFURLRef URLRef = NULL;
    if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve(itemRef, 0, &URLRef, NULL) == noErr) {
        if (URLRef) {
            NSURL *URL = (__bridge NSURL *)URLRef;
            NSString *path = URL.path;
            if (path) {
                itemDict[RESLoginItemsPathKey] = path;
            }
            CFRelease(URLRef);
        }
    }
    // Hidden
    CFBooleanRef hiddenRef = LSSharedFileListItemCopyProperty(itemRef,
                                                              kLSSharedFileListLoginItemHidden);
    if (hiddenRef) {
        if (hiddenRef == kCFBooleanTrue) {
            itemDict[RESLoginItemsHiddenKey] = @YES;
        }
        CFRelease(hiddenRef);
    }

    return itemDict;
}
```

The crash inside *loginItems*: namely *SharedFileListItemDeallocate* cause the crash. When NSArray's items auto-released. I suppose that:

```
SSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)item;
```

breaks ARC behavior and when loop finished it lead to release concrete item of the array. And second release will be called on function return which will lead to the crash.

Has anyone can prove or disprove my idea? Thanks.

Comment: do check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590649/a-simple-code-that-worked-fine-under-gc-but-started-crashing-in-arc

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are releasing `list` before using the items returned by

```
[self loginItemsForFileListRef:list]
```

If the items returned depend on `list` being valid, because the release of `list` might also trigger the release of the `items`, then you might crash when you try to iterate the returned items. Try to move the release of `list` after the for-loop that iterates the `items`. Sometimes you get bitten if you try to be overzealous about memory usage.